# Passing multiple functions with arguments to a main function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to execute a number of functions, in another function.

I'm trying to achieve something like this:

```
def first(thisString,thisNumber):
    print(thisString,thisNumber)

def second(a,b,c):
    print(a+b+c)

def runningOne(*args):
    for x in args:
        x[0](x[1])

one=[first,("try",15)]
two=[second,(4,3)]
runningOne(one,two)
```

But I don't know how to pass the arguments in the "runningOne" function.

Thanks,

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: He needs to unpack the tuple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you forgot to put an asterisk,

```py
def first(thisString,thisNumber):
    print(thisString,thisNumber)

def second(a,b,c):
    print(a+b+c)

def runningOne(*args):
    for x in args:
        x[0](*x[1])

one=[first,("try",15)]
two=[second,(4,3, 8)]
runningOne(one,two)
```

That's the fixed code, you had to put an asterisk before the `x[1]` and you also forgot to specify the third number in `two`.

Comment: Yes that fixed it, also realized I had missed an argument when I posted the code. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Use `*` to extract the parameters values

```
def runningOne(*args):
    for x in args:
        x[0](*x[1])
```

Comment: @Sujay `second` should recive 3 parameters, the OP used 2.

Comment: Great! That did it, I just had a typo in the initial code, because two[second,(4,3)] was missing the last argument, it's supposed to be something like : two[second,(4,3,2)] Thanks